# Android FPS meter

Tags: android, frame-rate

I want to create an app for FPS counting. In the scope of my application, it is possible with `Choreographer` that receives timing pulses from the display system.
But the original goal was a widget above all active application with an actual Frame Rate.

Does anyone know an approach how to do that?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://fpsmeter.github.io/

Comment: @leoderprofi Thanks for a link, manual says it requires attached device or emulator. And seems it uses adb tools like `adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo <PACKAGE_NAME> `. But, I want to create an isolated application.